# Elegant way to apply an array of filters to an array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array of filters (these would just be callbacks). And I want to apply all of these to my array elegantly. Currently these is what I would do:

```
const filters = [...];
let array = [...];

filters.forEach(filter => array = array.filter(filter));
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think you may want to put this in code review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is a *primarily opinion-based* question, so, you're going to get a lot of opinions based of experiences, Etc. Therefore, this question should be closed.

Comment: One alternate method: `array.filter(x => filters.every(f => f(x)))`

Comment: `array.filter(x => filters.every(y => y(x)));`

Comment: @AlexanderEdwards I hardly see enough code here to review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `filters` is an `array` of functions which returns `true` when parameter pass into criteria, a possible approach can be:

```
array.filter(x => filters.every(y => y(x)));
```